# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework' after installing WordPress on Windows Server

Tags: wordpress, windows-server

My Website is running on FrameWork 4.0 and It is working fine without any error.
I have just installed WordPress for Blog Purpose. And when I am trying to access it, It is showing error : `Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.`
Framework 4.0 setting is already there.
How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have .NET 4.0 installed on the server and that your IIS application pool is set to 4.0.

- Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
- Expand your server
- Select "Application Pools"
- Doubleclick on the AppPool that you have your WordPress Website configured for
- Change your .NET CLR Version to .NET v4

If V4 is not showing up you either don't have it installed or it didn't install 100% successfully.  If you know it is installed you can the aspnet_regiis tool ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).ASPX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)) to re-register .NET 4 with IIS.

Comment: IIS application pool is set to 4.0 as my website is running on 4.0 Framework only. I have Shared Hosting so I don't have access to all controls. I am getting this error only when WordPress is installed in main website project.